# Webintents "discover"

Tags: html, webintents

Could somebody explain to me what is the "discover" [WebIntents](http://webintents.org/discover) service?

> The discover intent is designed to let developers query the APIs and
>   services that might live on external services.  The "Discover"
>   protocol is intended to be a lightweight registry list.

Better still, could somebody provide me with an example?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebIntents/ContactsAPI <-- example

Comment: What is "webplatform" and what does it have to do with this question?  It is not mentioned in the question, comments, or any of the informative links provided.

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/meet-the-web-platform-companion

Comment: That's jargon, not a concrete thing or technology.  It doesn't need to be a tag.